# grep function returning unexpected results

Tags: r, regex

I'm having some trouble with the `grep()` function and am not sure why I'm getting the results that I am.

As a bare minimum reproducible example, I have about 98,000 elements in a character value in which an unknown amount of those elements look like the following:

```
[1] "1234567890,1000005238784,4,09-25-2014 15:01:21,09-25-2014 15:01:54,1,0987654321,0987654321,1,2,\\\\osp1\\ospdata\\714\\717\\725\\25-Sep-14\\dbs\\03.01.21.909_ad54b175ac1af10b60d60cd6ddd0c04b,Transcription\\annotation_1_1.htm,ROUHIP,,,ROUHIP,ROUHIP,1,0987654321,0,1,50,<html><head><title></title><style type=\"text/css\">"
```

I tried using the following regular expression to extract these elements, but it's coming back as empty:

```
h.1 <- grep('[:digit:]{10,11}[:punct:][:digit:]{13}', txt, value=T)
```

I also tried including ".*" at the end of the regex, but that didn't work either. I tried playing with a very simple vector to see if I could understand what was going on, but I was getting really weird results with that as well.

```
x <- c('1234', 'abc', '5', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'def')
grep('[:digit:]+', x, value=T)
[1] "def"
```

However, if I replace [:digit:] with "[0-9]" and remove the [:punct:] and just replace it with a comma, it works exactly as expected.

Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong and why the [:digit:] and/or [:punct:] options do not seem to be working?

Thanks!

Comment: Retry with `'[[:digit:]]{10,11}[[:punct:]][[:digit:]]{13}'`. Think of POSIX character class (`[:digit:]`) as `\d`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. You should have posted it as the answer to get the rep! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the POSIX pattern `[:digit:]` to match a digit inside a character class.

```
> x <- c('1234', 'abc', '5', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'def')
> grep('[[:digit:]]+', x, value=T)
[1] "1234" "5"
```